# Why might a usb wireless adaptor lose connection with a perfectly regular pattern

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, usb

I have recently installed a new wifi adaptor and I am observing a very strange sawtooth pattern for the adaptor throughput. It looks a bit like this:

```
 /\    /\    /\    /\    /\
/  \__/  \__/  \__/  \__/  \
```

There is 0 data transfer in the through and the cycle has about a 1.5 second periods and is extremely regular. A ping looks like this:

```
Pinging www.google.com [2607:f8b0:4004:80d::2004] with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 2607:f8b0:4004:80d::2004: time=25ms
Reply from 2607:f8b0:4004:80d::2004: time=3019ms
Reply from 2607:f8b0:4004:80d::2004: time=23ms
Reply from 2607:f8b0:4004:80d::2004: time=3024ms
Reply from 2607:f8b0:4004:80d::2004: time=23ms
Reply from 2607:f8b0:4004:80d::2004: time=3021ms
Reply from 2607:f8b0:4004:80d::2004: time=26ms
Reply from 2607:f8b0:4004:80d::2004: time=3022ms
```

The pattern looks exactly the same 2.4 of 5G.

Also the connection does not cycle for about the first 6 or seven seconds after connecting then the cycling kicks in.

It does not appear to be my ISP or my router since (I dont think):

A.) My old adapter works fine, I replaced it since the old adapter did not support 5G.

B.) The same pattern is seen if I ping another computer on the local network.

C.) The connection works splendid when it is wired.

I suspect it might be a usb thing rather than a network thing. Does anyone have any insight on what could cause this behavior.

Comment: Where you say "**I am observing a very strange sawtooth pattern for the adaptor throughput**" what are you observing this with exactly?

Comment: Windows performance monitor and the same thing showed up in slurms built in network monitoring tool which was running on a RHEL 7 vm running on Virtual Box.